# Django to get the input value to view page

Tags: python, django

My html looks like.

```
<html> <body>
    <input type="text" value='' id='txt' name='txt'/>
    <a href='#' onclick=fun(); > click me </a>


<script>
function fun()
{
    // this will assing the value to input tag mentioned above.
    $('#txt').attr('value':'previous'); 
}
</script>
```

I want to get the value of input type on click the `<a>` tag.
I have tried the controller page like this.

```
# views.py

def index():
    x=request.Get.get('txt')  
    # some operations here
```

I want to get the input tag value in view page without passing the value or id through url also.

Comment: `.attr('value': 'previous')` will raise an error. Consider changing it to `.attr({'value': 'previous'})` or `.attr('value', 'previous')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make an AJAX `POST` request, if you don't want to pass the value in URL. Here's how you can do this with jQuery.

```
function fun() {
    $('#txt').attr({'value':'previous'});
    $.ajax({
        url: '/url/to/view/',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {'txt': $('#txt').val()},
        success: function() {
            window.alert('Success!');
        },
        error: function() {
            window.alert('Error!!!');
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Oh, and as a side note, you will need to include `{{ csrf_token }}`, too, in the POST request.